# Connecting Laravel 4 (on OSX) to MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, macos, laravel, freetds

As above - trying to hook up a Laravel 4 app to an MSSQL DB. Currently I'm getting the Laravel 'Could not find driver' error page. I've found, compiled an installed an MSSQL.so extension using freeTDS and Homebrew for PHP as per this tutorial - http://lkrms.org/php-with-freetds-on-os-x-mavericks/

Running php -m from the command line lists out mssql.so in my installed extensions. I can also use freeTDS tsql command from terminal to successfully ping the target server.

Despite all this, Laravel still can't see the new driver and use it to connect, so there's obviously a piece of the puzzle I'm missing here, although a shedload of googling won't reveal it to me.

Any pointers guys?

Cheers in advance!

Comment: Forgot to add - this is all running on OSX's native Apache install, not through MAMP or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues connecting also.  Here is what I did.  I'm assuming that freeTDS is installed properly.

In database.php, when using a local installation make sure to use a comma instead of a colon between ip_number and port_number.  If server installation use colon.

```
'mssql' => array(
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => 'ip_number,port_number',  // Requires comma instead of colon before the port number for local installation
        'database' => 'database_name',
        'username' => 'user_name',
        'password' => 'password',
    ),
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Cheers for the answer dude, but no dice - I reckon I might still be stuck a few steps behind that. I'm pretty certain freeTDS is installed properly because as I said, I can ping the target DB with the tsql -h <host> -p <port> command in terminal. 

Aside from installing freeTDS and compiling/adding the mssql.so is there anything else you did to make Laravel take notice of the driver?